# Example of $X,Y$ normal ditributed s.t. $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[Y]$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I always thought that if $X$ and $Y$ were normal distributed then $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]$ implies $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. But my teacher said it was wrong. Could someone gives a counter-example ? I really don't see why is it wrong.

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal then certainly $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ implies $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable.  Let $B$ take values $\pm 1$, each with probability $1/2$, and independent of $X$.  Let $Y = B X$.  Then $Y$ has a standard normal
distribution, and
$$\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[B X^2] = \mathbb E[B] \mathbb E[X^2] = 0 = \mathbb E[X] \mathbb E[Y]$$
but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Well, in this case $X$ and $Y$ are not functionally independent, but they are still statistically independent as the joint density of $(X,Y)$ corresponds to the product of the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$: if $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ (and conversely).

Comment: @Bertrand No, they are not at all independent.   They have no joint density. Note that $X^2 = Y^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice example and clarification.

Comment: What do you men by $(X,Y)$ have no density ? Is this possible ? So if $(X,Y)$ have a density, then they must be independent ? (I don't understand the difference between independent and statically independent).

Comment: Two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are independent if and only if they have joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I also don't get why $(X,Y)$ has no density. They are not independent, so $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\neq f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, but why $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Pierre If they had a joint density, $\mathbb P(X^2 = Y^2)$ would be $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Interesting post. At the end, does it mean that we can't compute $\mathbb P((X,Y)\in A \times B)$ in general ? That really strange... we have two random variable, but $(X,Y)$ is not a random variable ?

Comment: We can compute it, just not as the double integral of a function.

Comment: To avoid confusion, let me use $A \times C$ instead of your $A \times B$, because I already defined a random variable $B$  Then $\mathbb P((X,Y) \in A \times C) = \left(\mathbb P(X \in A \cap C)  + \mathbb P(X \in A \cap(-C))\right)/2$.