# Compute $\mathbb{E}(2X_1+3X_2\mid X_1+3X_2-X_3=4)$ for $(X_k)$ i.i.d standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

$X_i,i=1,2,3$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables. Then $\mathbb{E}(2X_1+3X_2\mid X_1+3X_2-X_3=4)$=?

(Source: UOH PhD Entrance 2017)

I am not able to proceed too much with the problem except thinking of lengthy  calculation of finding the joint density of $2X_1+3X_2$ and $X_1+3X_2-X_3$. I am getting difficulty in finding the appropriate transformation. This being an multiple choice question, carrying only $1$ mark, I think I am not expected to use this method. Even if there is some nice idea to proceed with the problem, I suspect that I am missing that due to lack of adequate background. 
Hope I would be provided with hint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z:=X_1+3X_2-X_3$ and $Y:= 2X_1+3X_2$. Then $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,11)$ and  $Y=Z+X_1+X_3$.
Therefore $$\mathbb P\{Y\leq y\mid Z=z\}=\mathbb P\{X_1+X_3\leq y-z\mid Z=z\}$$
Now, by independence of $Z$ and $X_1+X_3$ (hint: correlation...), $$\mathbb P\{Y\leq y\mid Z=z\}=\mathbb P\{X_1+X_3\leq y-z\}$$ Since $X_1+X_3\sim \mathcal N(0,2)$, this proves that, for every $z$, $Y\mid Z=z\sim \mathcal N(z,2)$.

It follows that the desired conditional PDF is $$f_{Y\mid Z=z}(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{4}}$$
and that the desired conditional expectation is
$$\mathbb E[Y\mid Z=z]=z$$

Comment: What a pity! You competently show that $Y$ conditionally on $Z=z$ is normal $\mathcal N(z,2)$, but then you fail to use this fact to deduce with no further ado that $E(Y\mid Z)=Z$, in particular $E(Y\mid Z=4)=4$. (+1) to the revised version to come soon.

Comment: @Did I don't see how this fails, this answer looks like a hint to me.

Comment: @Did: thank you very much. Actually, you gave the best Hint.

Comment: @P.Quinton "I don't see how this fails" Please read carefully: the argument is valid but the OP fails to take advantage of it. "this answer looks like a hint to me" Good to know. Related how?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are normal distributed, it's not true that $(X,Y)$ is normal distributed (as show my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101645/example-of-x-y-normal-ditributed-s-t-mathbb-exy-mathbb-ey-mathbb-ey/3101658#3101658). And this, you can't prove that $Z$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent by proving that the covariance (or correlation) is $0$.

Comment: @Dylan: Since the $X_i$'s are independent, $(Z,X_1+X_2)$ is a Gaussian vector...